# WP 7.5 - How can I test tombstoning?

Tags: testing, windows-phone-7, tombstoning

In WP 7.0 it was easy to test the tombstone system - I'd hit the camera button then press back to get a tombstone/resume.  In WP 7.5 the app goes dormant for awhile, but appears to tombstone at an indeterminate time.  Is it possible to force this situation for testing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can test tombstoning using the emulator (this may even work on the phone I haven't tested it). Under the project properties, on the "Debug" panel, there is a checkbox named "Tombstone upon deactivation while debugging".

This setting will force the app to tombstone in the way it did before when the debugger is attached.

Comment: I believe it's in the `Debug` panel in project properties

Comment: This is great - know of any way for a tester to make this happen on a device?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test it on a device, try deploying the app to the phone with the debugger enabled and see if it forces a tombstone. For a test not connected to a PC I don't think you can force the tombstone.

Comment: That's about what I'd expect.  Thanks Nigel!

Comment: Its not working on Device that is why i have to google many time after all your answered gave me the hint. THANK